# How to calculate total number of bits in BitSet object?

Tags: java, bit, bitset

I want to calculate the total number of bits in a `BitSet` object. The method `length` returns the "logical size" of the `BitSet`: the index of the highest set bit in the `BitSet` plus one, while method `cardinality` will give the total number of bits set to 1 in the object.

I want to calculate the total number of bits including both 0s and 1s. How do I do that?

Comment: I don't think this deserves downvoting. The difference between `length` and `size` is confusing, the naming IMHO very inappropriate, and the documentation sucks.

Answer (score 2):

How about [`BitSet.size()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#size%28%29)?.....

Comment: size will returns the number of bits of space actually in use by this BitSet to represent bit values.

Comment: I want to calculate number of bits and not the space.

Comment: @Saurabh: I don't think `BitSet` is designed for that; there is no concept of the "highest" 0.

Comment: I want to create a binary representation from bitset object, any idea how can I do that?

Comment: I don't understand how `BitSet#size()` does not meet your requirement. You mentioned that you're looking for both the zero- and one-valued bits. Isn't that the same as asking how many bits can be represented by the `BitSet` instance at the moment?

Comment: @Saurabh there is no difference between the number of bits and the space.

Answer (score 1):

The getObjectSize(Object o) method in the Instrumentation library is your guy: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html

There are a few threads on this.

- http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077496/testing-debugging/java-tip-130--do-you-know-your-data-size-.html
- [In Java, what is the best way to determine the size of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object)

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

The [site](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Convertbitsettointarrayandstring.htm) shows how to convert a BitSet to binary String. Then just calculate the `string.length()`

Comment: Why was this marked down? If you think it's incorrect/misleading, at least explain why.

Comment: @Disco 3: It's like calculating the length of the String by first putting all its characters into a List and then reverting it and then calling list.size(). Totally inefficient. Moreover, the method linked is totally broken and the result would be always 32.

Comment: I was wrong... the method there works with `int` only, so it's not broken, just unusable for this question. And inefficient (needless reverse) and useless (see `Integer.toString(int i, int radix)`).